# How to reset Hangman game without reseting the score?

Tags: javascript

I am working on this hangman game and I am having trouble getting the "losses" / "wins" counter to work.

It seems I have the losses counter to work but the number of guesses will go into the negatives. It will count the game as a loss but will not reset it.

When I set the win count it counts every user click and not the entire word. SO far everything I have tried with the game has failed.

How get the game to reset after someone has lost or won while keeping the score?

```
function getItem() {
var array = [
    {
        answer: "harvey",
        hint: "Thank you Harvey, I prefer you too."
    },

    {
        answer: "titanic",
        hint: "Jack, I’m flying!"
    },

    {
        answer: "jaws",
        hint: "You’re Gonna Need A Bigger Boat…"
    },

    {
        answer: "rocky",
        hint: "ADRIAAAAAAAAAAAN!!!!!!!!"
    },

    {
        answer: "casablanca",
        hint: "We'll always have Paris."
    },

    {
        answer: "braveheart",
        hint: "They may take away our lives, but they'll never take our freedom!"
    },

    {
        answer: "goodfellas",
        hint: "As far back as I can remember, I always wanted to be a gangster."
    },

    {
        answer: "diehard",
        hint: "Nine million terrorists in the world and I gotta kill one with feet smaller than my sister."
    },

    {
        answer: "chinatown",
        hint: "Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown."
    },

    {
        answer: "psycho",
        hint: "A boy's best friend is his mother.",
    }

]


var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
return array[randomNumber];



  };


var randomThing = getItem()
document.getElementById("hint-text").innerHTML = ("Here is your 
hint.... " + randomThing.hint.italics());

var blankSpacesAnswer = [];
var blanksAndSuccesses = document.getElementById("blankspaces-text");
for (var i = 0; i < randomThing.answer.length; i++) {
blankSpacesAnswer[i] = "_";
console.log(blankSpacesAnswer);
blanksAndSuccesses.innerHTML = ("Your word: " + 
blankSpacesAnswer.join(" "));
};

var currentWord;
var guessingWord = [];
var winCounter = 0;
var lossCounter = 0;
var numGuesses = 12;
var letterGuessed = "";
var wrongGuesses = [];
var remainingLetters = randomThing.answer.length;

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
var userGuess = event.key;
console.log(userGuess);
var answerLetterArray = randomThing.answer.split("");
guessingWord.length = answerLetterArray.length;
console.log(answerLetterArray);

if (remainingLetters > 0) {
    var guessesEl = document.getElementById("blankspaces-text")
    guessesEl.innerHTML = blankSpacesAnswer.join(" ")

    var notFound = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < answerLetterArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(answerLetterArray[i]);

        if (userGuess === answerLetterArray[i]) {
            blankSpacesAnswer[i] = userGuess
        }

        else if (answerLetterArray[i] !== userGuess) {
            notFound = true;
        }

        blanksAndSuccesses.innerHTML = ("Your word:   " + 
   blankSpacesAnswer.join(" "));
        document.getElementById("usser-guesses-text").innerHTML = 
    ("Your guesses: " + userGuess);
        document.getElementById("wins-text").textContent = ("Wins: " + 
   winCounter);
    }

    if (notFound === true) {
        numGuesses--;
    }
    if (numGuesses === 0)
        lossCounter++;
   }


   document.getElementById("guesses-left").textContent = ("Number of 
   guesses: " + numGuesses);
   document.getElementById("losses-text").textContent = ("Losses: " + 
   lossCounter);

   };
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Show your research. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I've created a code sandbox here with some html code I assumed to be there: https://codesandbox.io/s/k2xl54nlyv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your trouble seems to be that the game just starts right away with no real notion of setting it up, winning it or losing it.

So while you're tracking the state of your guesses, you are not tracking the state of the game itself.

I'd suggest splitting the code into a few parts:

1. Setup
2. Initialization
3. Run / Loop
4. End of game

The **Setup** phase should set up the user interface, key handlers and so on.

**Initialization** starts the game (select a random word, set number of guesses to what you want, etc.)

The **Run / Loop** will just wait for your input and track the state of the game. If a `win` or `lose` situation occurs, it should end the game accordingly.

When reaching **End of game**, you can reset / restart the game by going back into the **Initialization** phase.

If you'd put your code into functions `setup()`, `initialize()`, `run()` and `win()` / `lose()`, you can call these functions when you want/need to switch the game state.

**Update:** [A solution for your hangman game (and some fixes)](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3v27n5vl3)

Comment: Wow.... Thank you! You explained this so clearly. I understand what you mean by breaking the code up into different sections such has, setup/run/win/lose. 

You break it down into the snippets of code that will need to run together in functions so that you can call those functions later on. In my code, I was running it all at once under the onkeyup function. 


This is extremely helpful!